# How to center the nonzero values within 2D numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I'd like to locate all the nonzero values within a 2D numpy array and move them so that the image is centered. I do not want to pad the array because I need to keep it the same shape. For example:

```
my_array = np.array([[1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 2, 4], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]])
# center...

>>> [[0 0 0 0]
     [0 1 1 0]
     [0 2 4 0]
     [0 0 0 0]]
```

But in reality the arrays I need to center are much larger (like 200x200, 403x403, etc, and they are all square). I think `np.nonzero` and `np.roll` might come in handy, but am not sure of the best way to use these for my large arrays.

Comment: How do you define being in center?

Comment: @Tai I guess ideally I'd like to set the coordinates of the centroid of my image equal to the origin (given that I already have coordinates of the centroid).

Comment: Do you already come up with a method to solve smaller matrix?  If so, you should share it with people. Also, more examples would be helpful to people.

Comment: Not yet. The reason I say I already have the coordinates of the centroid is because I'm using the `astropy` package `photutils`, which has features that return the coordinates of the centroids of objects in your image.

Comment: Are the lines independent? From the example you provided, it seems that the line are centered one by one first, then the bloc [[1 1][2 4]] is centered vertically...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The combination of `nonzero` and `roll` can be used for this purpose. For example, if `k=0` in the loop shown below, then `np.any` will identify the rows that are not identically zero. The first and last such rows are noted, and the shift along the axis is computed so that after the shift, `(first+last)/2` will move to the middle row of the array. Then the same is done for columns.

```
import numpy as np
my_array = np.array([[1, 1, 0, 0], [2, 4, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]])
print(my_array)   # before
for k in range(2):
    nonempty = np.nonzero(np.any(my_array, axis=1-k))[0]
    first, last = nonempty.min(), nonempty.max()
    shift = (my_array.shape[k] - first - last)//2
    my_array = np.roll(my_array, shift, axis=k)
print(my_array)   # after
```

Before:

```
[[1 1 0 0]
 [2 4 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]]
```

After:

```
[[0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 0]
 [0 2 4 0]
 [0 0 0 0]]
```

Alternative: `np.count_nonzeros` can be used in place of `np.any`, which allows to potentially set some threshold for the number of nonzero pixels that are deemed "enough" to qualify a row as a part of the image.