# Python: Return position and size of arbitrary/teeth shapes in image using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, object-detection, scikit-image

I'm very new to the image processing and object detection. I'd like to extract/identify the position and dimensions of teeth in the following image:

[image: Image processing]

Here's what I've tried so far using OpenCV:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

planets = cv2.imread('model.png', 0)
canny = cv2.Canny(planets, 70, 150)
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(canny,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,40, param1=10,param2=16,minRadius=10,maxRadius=80)

circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))

for i in circles[0,:]:
   # draw the outer circle
   cv2.circle(planets,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(255,0,0),2)

   # draw the center of the circle
   cv2.circle(planets,(i[0],i[1]),2,(255,0,0),3)

cv2.imshow("HoughCirlces", planets)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This is what I get after applying canny filter:
[image: applied canny filter]

This is the final result:
[image: detected teeth]

I don't know where to go from here. I'd like to get all of the teeth identified. How can I do that?

I'd really appreciate any help..

Answer (score 3):

Note that the teeth-structure is more-or-less a parabola (upside-down). If you could somehow guess the parabolic shape that defines the centroids of those blobs (teeth), then your problem could be simplified to a reasonable extent. I have shown a red line that passes through the centers of the teeth.

[image]

I would suggest you to approach it as follows:

1. **Binarize** your image (background=0, else 1). You could use [`sklearn.preprocessing.binarize`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.binarize.html).
2. Calculate the centroid of all the non-zero pixels. This is the central blue circle in the image. Call this `structure_centroid`. See this: [How to center the nonzero values within 2D numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51716954/how-to-center-the-nonzero-values-within-2d-numpy-array).
3. Make polar slices of the entire image, centered at the location of the `structure_centroid`. I have shown a cartoon image of such polar slices (triangular semi-transparent). Cover complete 360 degrees. See this: [`polarTransform` library](https://pypi.org/project/polarTransform/).
4. Determine the position of the centroid of the non-zero pixels for each of these polar slices. See these:

   - [find the distance between a point and a curve python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16158402/find-the-distance-between-a-point-and-a-curve-python).
   - [Find the minimum distance from a point to a curve](http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2013/02/14/Find-the-minimum-distance-from-a-point-to-a-curve/).
5. The array containing these centroids gives you the locus (path) of the average location of the teeth. Call this `centroid_path`.
6. Run an elimination/selection algorithm on the circles you were able to detect, that are closest to the `centroid_path`. Use a threshold distance to drop the outliers.

This should give you a good approximation of the teeth with the circles.

I hope this helps.

Comment: is it possible to give me a code sample for this? I'm still new with this.. thanks

Comment: Sorry, these are the steps and that's all I can give you here. But the steps that I have laid down for you, you could work on each of them and should be able to find existing solutions on stackoverflow (most likely). But a solution like this could take hours. So, all the best. You may also want to consider using `skimage`, in case you are new to `OpenCV`. Another library that you would find useful is `sklearn` (perhaps: depends on the usecase).

Comment: @SolidSnake Ok. I added a few more links to point you to possible existing solution for each step. But frankly speaking this is potentially a nice project and it could take time. Which is, in my opinion out of scope for stackoverflow answers. Best.

Comment: @SolidSnake If you think the idea/answer helped, please consider **`upvoting`** and/or **`accepting`**. Thank you.

Comment: I've tried to follow your advice and it took me nowhere unfortunately. There's no obvious answer for this as the shapes of the teeth are inconsistent. Also when I convert the image to binary/thresholding or using other techniques like canny or edging, the shapes most of the times are incomplete therefore they won't look like a full circular/blob shape. I've tried to use contours as well as convexhull to detect these shapes but they always return incomplete result. I'm wondering is there a way to detect these incomplete shapes?

Comment: @SolidSnake What I suggested was only to help to eliminate the circles that are far from that red line or the circles that are so small that they cannot represent a tooth. This needs to be preceded by what you had already done. Does this help at all?

Comment: ConvexHull and Contour detection may only give the contours that you see, but that does not let you device a logic to separate out the logical-boundary for an individual tooth.

Comment: I was able to eliminate these small/big circles using the properties given with HoughCircles. However, the problem now is that I have other samples of teeth with partial/incomplete circular/blob shapes (normally for the front teeth). These shapes are very hard to be detected using HoughCircles. So I'm thinking maybe I should apply different filtering for the upper part of the image which will help detecting the front teeth. However, using this technique doesn't make the accuracy level reach 100%

Comment: Does HoughElipses help if you use it on the teeth. Since you are then giving another degree of freedom to the single radius constraint of a circle, may be that will help. Take a look at this for blob-detection as well: https://www.learnopencv.com/blob-detection-using-opencv-python-c/

Comment: It does detect circularity of the object but you have to optimize the params to make it work with these incomplete objects. However, the accuracy of the detection isn't 100%. As for the blob detection I've already tested it, it wouldn't work if these blobs/teeth objects are very close to each other or doesn't perform full closed shapes. I've combined that with morphology filters but still doesn't provide accurate results. All in all I think there's no perfect way to do this unless if I write something from scratch..